# Django says name 'form' not defined, but import exists

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a user form and a profile form as below:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from .models import Profile

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2']

class RegisterProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
    postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    countrycode = forms.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['address','postcode','countrycode']
```

These are imported into views.py in the code below and if valid...

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import RegisterUserForm,RegisterProfileForm,UserUpdateForm,ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        p_form = RegisterProfileForm(request.POST)

        if u_form.is_valid and p_form.is_valid:
            from django import forms
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
```

However, when I post the form I get "Name Error at register... name 'form' is not defined" and the offending line of code is: username = form.cleaned_data.get('username'), in other words as soon as I reference form.cleaned_data, django objects.

This used to work. In desperation I imported django.forms just before referencing forms.cleaned_data (it wasn't there before) but unsurprisingly I still get "Name Error at register... name 'form' is not defined".

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong, or point out things to check?

Comment: You imported module `formS`. But is the code you have variable `form` which is not created but used (`form.cleaned_data...`). You probably wanted to use `u_form` or `p_form`

Comment: I should be able to reference form because it's in django.forms, which I am importing. u_form is a completely different class that does not have form.cleaned_data...

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of form's `cleaned_data` is not correct. Try like this(check the code comments for explanation):

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        p_form = RegisterProfileForm(request.POST)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():  # is_valid is a method, not property
            username = u_form.cleaned_data.get('username')  # get cleaned data form a form instance, like 'u_form' or 'p_form'
            first_name = u_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
```

More information can be found in [**`is_valid()` documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) and [**`cleaned_data` documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

Comment: Nope. You've not looked at my code. My forms are Django model forms - UserCreationForm to be specific, so is_valid is fine the way it is being used and Django is not objecting or I could not be at the line where form.cleaned_data is a problem. Moreover, I can't have u_form.cleaned_data.get because cleaned_data belongs to django.forms, not to django.contrib.auth.forms, which is where UserCreationForm comes from.

Comment: @Dele I think you are misunderstanding how django forms work. Forms and ModelForms are the same when it comes to how to validate and get cleaned data. and can you print `u_form.is_valid` (without brackets) and see what output you get. Probably you will see something containing `bound method` instead of True or False. Finally, can you try my answer ?

Comment: If I change the code to exactly as you have described it, Django determines that request.method is not POST and goes straight to the else statement, which subsequently fails with UnboundLocal because the code associated with it request.method not being POST references context that has not been defined. I get a different error that has nothing to do with the original problem - I referenced form.cleaned_data.get, which is in django.forms, a library I have imported, but which seemingly cannot be found. All I want to know is: why can't it be found?

Comment: that means your is_valid() method is failing, means your form is not validating